# Full Crawl running along Continuous?

Tags: search, crawl

I was having trouble with the incremental crawl schedule not implementing on schedule.  I changed over to continuous crawl.  Does a full crawl run when the Continuous Crawl is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

No, and in fact you do not want to run a full crawl outside of troubleshooting a specific issue that only a FC will resolve. The reason being is that when your content size grows significantly, executing a FC will cause search freshness to degrade significantly.